# Facebook graph api's <fb:login-button> not recognizing scope="..." attribute

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

When I click `<fb:login-button scope="user_photos">`, the login popup window says `YOUR_APP will receive the following info: your public profile.`, and user_photos permission isn't recognised.

I'll show some more details.

I have a facebook app which used to work, but now doesn't work anymore. (so facebook developer console thing etc should be correctly set up) I'm guessing this is because of their API version update, because it stopped working suddenly even though I didn't make any change to my code.

I inspected the code, and now I'm facing a problem that permission isn't recognised well.
As I mentioned above, I'm using `<fb:login-button>` button for login method, and it's not working correctly.

Here's login button HTML. 
(the code is indented for readability, and also I've confirmed from developer console that this HTML is actually received and recognised by browser.)

```
<fb:login-button 
    id="fb_login"
    scope="user_photos"
    onlogin="checkLoginState();"
    size="xlarge">
        Start Using Right Now
</fb:login-button>
```

And here's what runs on document ready. Basically same as what tutorial says.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : 'XXX',
        cookie     : true,  
        xfbml      : true,  
        version    : 'v2.1' 
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
};

(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Please tell me if you guys need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, probably solved. Since sometime in the past, we need facebook guys' review of the app before using specific group of permissions.

Check this out for the list of the permissions and which one needs their review and authorisation.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2

You gotta fill in these long forms to get them to review the app.
I'm waiting for the response and it said it'll take like less than 7 business days to get the response.